# How do you create 2 Rectangle objects that will collide and be detected in Java?

Tags: java, collision, detection, rectangles, jcreator

Also, is it possible to collide 2 Oval objects?

```
   public void paint(Graphics g){
            g.setColor(Color.green);<br/>
            g.fillRect(k, l, 100, 100);<br/>
                g.setColor(Color.blue);<br/>
                g.fillRect(n, m, 100, 100);<br/>
            g.setColor(Color.red);<br/>
            for(int i=0; i<2; i++){<br/>
               g.fillOval((int)x[i],(int)y[i],diameter,diameter);<br/>
            }<br/>
        }
```

Comment: Any two objects, regardless of their shape, can collide. Can you handle the collision is the real question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you are using Swing for your graphics. Although actually providing code for your question would be a rather complex task, I will try to guide you in the correct direction.

It might be best to encapsulate the rectangles (or ovals) into their own classes. Give the objects a method like `drawSelf(Graphics g)` and pass in the Graphics object. Also, give the classes fields to keep track of their current positions and sizes.

Then, for collisions, you might try making a class along the lines of a `CollisionDetector`. All of your shape objects would have-a CollisionDetector, and everytime a shape moves you ask all shapes to check with their `CollisionDetector`s, which in turn check all other Detectors to see if they overlap.